In what way are we one in Christ Jesus?
Galatians 3:28

There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free, there
is neither male nor female; for you are all one in Christ Jesus.

What is the word "one" trying to convey here?
In what way is it trying to be communicated that we are, "one in Christ Jesus"?
Is the idea supposed to be one of the following?:

Spiritual unity. (Where all believers are indwelt by the Holy Spirit and are part of the body of Christ)
Equality in salvation. (Where salvation through faith in Christ is available to all)
Identity in Christ. (Where our primary identity becomes that of “Christian” or “follower of Christ.”)
Oneness in purpose. (Where we live for Christ and to carry out His mission in the world.)
Inheritance. (Where we share in the inheritance of the promises of God)
Substance. (Where we are of the same substance as agued for John 10:30)


To me Col 1:16 "in" [created in] is "in" His hand as biro in hand; but Gal 3:28 "in" as blood vessel. i.e., incorporated/internal. Biro under control, but blood vessel "part of".

substance / nature could be argued - John 17:21 21that all of them may be one, as You, Father, are in Me, and I am in You. May they also be in Us, so that the world may believe that You sent Me.


For as the body is one, and hath many members, and all the members of that one body, being many, are one body: so also is Christ. For by one Spirit are we all baptized into one body, whether we be Jews or Gentiles, whether we be bond or free; and have been all made to drink into one Spirit.  [1 Corinthians 12:12,13 KJV]

Under the Headship of Christ, there is one body.
That is to say, once there has been true repentance (a baptism of repentance which fills up the interior, as it were, and the water turns to wine) and once, through hearing and receiving the Gospel of Jesus Christ, there is an obedient faith, then one is baptised into that one body, publicly, and confessedly.
Since the Person of the Holy Spirit is He by whom both penitence and faith are effected within the individual soul and mind and heart, and since, once faith brings the penitent to Christ himself, there is union, in spirit, then it is evident that the spirit of the penitent believer is in union, through the Holy Spirit, with Christ Himself.
Therefore, each individual within that same body, under that same Headship, in the same faith, is united, in spirit, with each other such individual within that body.
As Paul puts it, we all drink into one Spirit.
It as though there is a volume of water, and each partakes of that water, but instead of the water coming into us, it is we who are drawn into the volume, drinking into one Spirit.
There is such a union, of each member, with that Holy Spirit, that Divine Person, that each individual, therefore, is also in unity with each other member.
This is a living, spiritual matter.
It is not an external or formal membership.

There, of course, follows on the other five matters listed in the question.
It would entail many chapters for me to cover all of those to the degree that they each deserve.

I would certainly add 1 Corinthians ch3 v16 (my favourite quotation on unity) to the evidence that this is Paul's understanding. The community is God's temple, which must not be destroyed by disunity, because God's Spirit is dwelling "in you" (plural).

I appreciate the answer. I think this provides a solid foundation. +1

The answer to this question about the meaning of "one" in Gal 3:28 is supplied by the first half of the verse (my translation):

There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free; there
is neither male nor female; for you are all one in Christ Jesus.

The "one in Christ Jesus" means that there exists no longer the human divisions of sexuality, financial resources, ethnicity and religious differences - we are all simply Christians = saved sinners, saved by free grace with a single, unified purpose to fulfil the Gospel commission to make more disciples.
Paul and others expressed this in other ways as well:

1 Cor 2:16 - “For who has known the mind of the Lord, so as to instruct Him?” But we have the mind of Christ.
Phil 2:5 - Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ Jesus
Eph 4:22-24 - to put off your former way of life, your old self, which is being corrupted by its deceitful desires; to be renewed in the spirit of your minds; and to put on the new self, created to be like God in true righteousness and holiness.
Phil 2:2 - then make my joy complete by being like-minded, having the same love, being united in spirit and purpose.
Rom 8:6 - The mind of the flesh is death, but the mind of the Spirit is life and peace
1 Peter 1:13 - Therefore prepare your minds for action. Be sober-minded. Set your hope fully on the grace to be given you at the revelation of Jesus Christ.
Heb 8:10 - For this is the covenant I will make with the house of Israel after those days, declares the Lord. I will put My laws in their minds and inscribe them on their hearts. And I will be their God, and they will be My people.


I appreciate the answer. Easy to understand, solid, and straightforward . +1

No more human division. Simple and straight forward.

All six bullet-points below the question are included in this 'oneness' in Christ Jesus. That becomes clear when Christians grasp the massive significance of what belonging to Christ by faith encompasses. The scope of this is vast, and is described in the New Testament as a "mystery" that has only been revealed with the significance of Christ's resurrection. That is why the Apostle Paul detailed in Ephesians 3:3-19 how the mystery of Christ was revealed, so that the Gentiles also "should be fellow-heirs, and of the same body, and partakers of his promise in Christ by the gospel... to make men see what is the fellowship of the mystery, which from the beginning of the world hath been hid in God... " But now, Paul says, the church (ecclesia) knows the wisdom of God in Christ which strengthens

"by his Spirit the inner man; That Christ may dwell in your hearts by
faith; that ye, being rooted and grounded in love, may be able to
comprehend with all saints what is the breadth, and length, and depth,
and height; and to know the love of Christ, which passeth knowledge,
that ye might be filled with all the fulness of God." Ephesians
3:16-19 A.V.

Those who are born from above come under the headship of Christ, who is head of his Church (ecclesia) as one body, taken from his side as Eve was from the first Adam. The parallel is there with Christ, the last Adam, and the Church, his bride.

"For we are members of his body, of his flesh, and of his bones. For
this cause shall a man leave his father and mother, and shall be
joined unto his wife, and they two shall be one flesh. This is a great
mystery: but I speak concerning Christ and the church." Ephesians
5:30-31 A.V.
"For as the body is one, and hath many members, and all the members of
that one body, being many, are one body: so also is Christ. For by one
Spirit are we all baptized into one body, whether we be Jews or
Gentiles, whether we be bond or free; and have been all made to drink
into one Spirit." 1 Corinthians 12:12-13 A.V.

The wonder of just what it means to be "one in Christ Jesus" will never be fully grasped by Christians this side of eternity, but at "the marriage supper of the Lamb", then we will know, as we are known.

You might want to check the definition of enormity, Anne.  ;-)

@Dieter   Oh, wow, there was I thinking it was a better way of saying 'enormousness'! Thank you, kind sir, for correcting me. Nice to learn something new today; I won't make that  awful mistake again!

Usage guides often weigh in on this subject, in admirably measured prose, and tend to recommend using enormity for “evil” and enormousness for “great size.” Merriam Webster.

What is the word "one" trying to convey here?
I would like to offer an answer to just this part of the OP's question, since there is an idiom here that underpins everything else.
I always aim for a firm distinction between (as here) reading, which some people call "studying words" - and translating - which is a higher function. Ideally we want separation of functions and this is about passing a reading up to inform the translators.
It's very possible there are simple errors in this answer, but if the many stages are set out, and the reading is also a writing, then it's hopefully convenient for corrections to be drawn, and of wider benefit to mine and others' understanding.
For this answer I assume Galatians is from a trilingual Paul of Tarsus. I'm not at all a historian and due to his famous description of himself in Philippians 3:5, as a "Hebrew of Hebrews", I'm prone to imagining him as having Aramaic and Hebrew above Greek.
TL;DR - see Meyer's commentary
For ye all are one, ye form a single moral person; so that now those distinctions of individuals outside of Christianity appear as non-existent, completely merged in that higher unity to which ye are all raised in virtue of your fellowship of life with Christ. This is the εἷς καινὸς ἄνθρωπος
https://biblehub.com/commentaries/galatians/3-28.htm
Meyer is an authority on Greek grammar and idiom in the NT, and expresses it with crystal clarity. His commentary often works through very fine distinctions at the level of which way round words are. So he will have been through the topic that follows, it's just that we can't see how from just 1 sentence. And the OP may need to see how.
There are some textual variants, which I'll mention only briefly in case the OP needs to follow these up with a critical apparatus. They would affect the important bit of the verse, but they don't come from the MSS the translators give weight to.
From Nestle-Aland, 1981:-

πάντες γὰρ ὑμεῖς εἷς ἐστε ἐν Χριστῷ Ἰησοῦ (Berean Greek New Testament 2016, used throughout in this answer)
πάντες γὰρ ὑμεῖς ἕν ἐστε ἐν Χριστῷ Ἰησοῦ
πάντες γὰρ ὑμεῖς εἷς ἐστε ἐν Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ
πάντες γὰρ ὑμεῖς εἷς ἐστε Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ

==============================
πάντες γὰρ ὑμεῖς εἷς ἐστε ἐν Χριστῷ Ἰησοῦ (Galatians 3:28)
==============================
TRANSLATING NUMBER
The grammar difficulty is in how the two (potentially three) languages handle the plurality of the objects of plural verbs.
E.g. from Aristotle's De Partibus Animalium (670a.25~)
All animals have two spleens - - echei panta ta enaima duo ta splanchna tauta mona
English and Greek do the same thing with the verb's object - we take it from context that it isn't all the animals with two spleens to go round between them. You can probably see where this is going.
Slightly more than English, I'll submit Greek has a tendency to mentally separate plural verbs into a bundle of separate singular ones.
We ask a hundred people to take off their hats, but in Greek it can be their hat.
I couldn't find this topic (let alone the precise rules) in Jay (1958) for NT Greek. Moule (1982) doesn't have a section on verbs' number, but it might be in there somewhere under another heading.
I think I have it in North & Hillard's Greek Prose Composition for Schools (1954) which is pitched at 11-year-olds and somehow they've slipped this little gem into the third lesson and expected everyone to still remember it when they get to Paul of Tarsus.
"(b) with regard to Number-the Predicate may be plural or may be singular in agreement with the nearest subject." (predicate="object" in a subject/object distinction)
====
As I've already intimated, I implicitly trust Meyer but it's about working through carefully so that the OP can follow what the word "one" conveys.
The idiom of most of our translations lends itself to "being one" with one on the predicate side of the verb. But in Greek the numeral is an adjective agreeing with the subject.
==============================
ὑμεῖς εἷς ἐστε - - you are all one in Christ Jesus
double check: humeis=we is (nominative plural) ; heis=1 nominative adjective so agrees with humeis ; este is plural agreeing with humeis
Was this natural idiom in NT Greek? To have the singular numeral adjective in agreement with the plural personal pronoun.
It's like saying "one cats sit on the mat"
I suppose we might feel the number of heis when in Greek it isn't a grammatical property of the numeral. Their numerals don't possess number... and it isn't necessarily because they are the number. How do they say "tens and twenties"?
Cambridge Greek Grammar has this (archive.org often needs an account to borrow  but it's free):-
https://archive.org/details/greekgrammar0000smyt/page/108/mode/2up
(In Attic Greek, they say kata deka kata eikosi.)
Point e here is interesting. Abstract and collective numbers are feminine.
Three ways forward occur:-

Check if NT Greek is the same or this Grammar covers it
Look for usages of heis and a plural verb
(- Check if this was a difference from Ancient Hebrew or Aramaic)

The last one is a last resort that is too often used as a first resort, perhaps because it's easy with a Strongs Concordance and appears 'deep'. If Paul is translating an idea, a translator's product is only in the new language.
===
For NT Greek, Blass and Funk
https://archive.org/details/greekgrammarofne0000blas/page/34/mode/2up
(the reason I leave NT Grammar to this stage is that Paul is such a big proportion of the surviving corpus, so saying "this is fine in NT Greek" to some extent reduces to saying "Paul got away with this")
This grammar doesn't shed light on the topic, but the way it covers the topic in terms of difference from the earlier language means it's probably safe enough to move on.
====
εἷς  -  -  "The Meaning of One... The Meaning of Two... The Meaning of Many..."
Liddell & Scott (1882) isn't clear enough for this word for this purpose, and I can't manage to get Perseus Project to return it at all, but Strongs is online and has about 100 occurrences
https://biblehub.com/greek/eis_1520.htm
To me these ones seem like the closest:-
Matthew 26:21 Adj-NMS  - - GRK: ὑμῖν ὅτι εἷς ἐξ ὑμῶν
Matthew 27:38 Adj-NMS - - GRK: δύο λῃσταί εἷς ἐκ δεξιῶν
John 8:9 Adj-NMS - - GRK: ἀκούσαντες ἐξήρχοντο εἷς καθ' εἷς
1 Corinthians 8:6 Adj-NMS - - GRK: ἀλλ' ἡμῖν εἷς θεὸς ὁ
I'll submit none of those ones match, and it's not there.
The feminine μία and neuter ἓν do have closer matches to Galatians 3:28 though so I will try to work through these. μία has 35, ἓν has 67.
I propose to skip the other cases.
==========================
Matthew 19:5-6
[...]καὶ ἔσονται οἱ δύο εἰς σάρκα μίαν;’ - - and they will be the two into one flesh
ὥστε οὐκέτι εἰσὶν δύο ἀλλὰ σὰρξ μία [...] - - So they are no longer two but one flesh
In this last part the verb is still in agreement with the man and woman. This is also a difficult idiom: I read it that ἀλλὰ contrasts "they are two" with "one flesh [is]". I don't think it's a clear parallel to Paul's construction.
Mark has the same words but in one verse. (Mark 10:8)
καὶ ἔσονται οἱ δύο εἰς σάρκα μίαν·’ ὥστε οὐκέτι εἰσὶν δύο ἀλλὰ μία σάρξ.
I submit that the second part is marked idiom and needs the first part to be understood. Our division into verses might not have served Matthew's version well for modern readers.
==========================
John 10:16
καὶ γενήσονται* μία ποίμνη, εἷς ποιμήν - - they will become one flock, one shepherd
So the same construction as Paul. Like Mark this also derives some clarity from what precedes it. And having γίνομαι signifies the change of condition.
I have other sheep that are not of this sheep pen. I must bring them also. They too will listen to my voice, and there shall be one flock and one shepherd.
This looks like three familiar idioms followed by a marked one. And all expressed as pairs which is neat.
We can now do a productive comparison to Paul:-
There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free, there is neither male nor female; for you are all one in Christ Jesus.
I submit that here the preceding three pair-ideas contrast with the concluding idea rather than clarifying it. On the basis the last one is combined but the preceding are not ; and the preceding are negatives.
==========================
Acts 19:34
φωνὴ ἐγένετο μία ἐκ πάντων - - one voice became from many
This is a simpler idiom from Paul. But it refers to one voiced idea emerging from a cacophony, not the union of the crowd's voices into, like, one actual voice. So it's not helpful to Galatians and may be another example of how translation loses the details of thought.
==========================
For ἕν,
John 17:22-3
Κἀγὼ τὴν δόξαν ἣν δέδωκάς μοι δέδωκα αὐτοῖς, ἵνα ὦσιν ἓν καθὼς ἡμεῖς ἕν·
ἐγὼ ἐν αὐτοῖς καὶ σὺ ἐν ἐμοί, ἵνα ὦσιν τετελειωμένοι εἰς ἕν, ἵνα γινώσκῃ ὁ κόσμος ὅτι σύ με ἀπέστειλας καὶ ἠγάπησας αὐτοὺς καθὼς ἐμὲ ἠγάπησας.
“I have given them the glory you gave me, so they may be one as we are one. I in them and you in me, that they may become perfectly one, so that the world may know that you sent me and loved them even as you loved me.
Here ...ὦσιν ... ἡμεῖς ἕν corresponds with  ὑμεῖς εἷς ἐστε but I submit there are three differences.

The whole point of ἡμεῖς=we, is that it combines a plural into a singular.

There is more clarifying context.

re. εἰς ἕν this is the same idiom as Plato uses in Republic Book IX 588d for his representation of the soul as a man, a lion, and a monster carved into one image. If this was still strongly felt in John's time it might qualify καθὼς such that the union of the Son with the Father is of the familiar metaphysical type Plato described. Which then has Father+Son  extended to Son+Christian implying a Father+Son+Christian unity, from which the Christian-Christian unity might derive.


==========================
Conclusion
There is a subtle range in the idioms NT Greek uses to express metaphysical combination. Notwithstanding some minor differences, Galatians 3:28 has at least two close parallels in John 10:16 and John 17:22-3, and a similar construction in a shared phrase of Matthew 19:5-6 and Mark 10:8.
In all four of these parallels can be found close-in devices that served to clarify the idiom, and the absence of this in Paul might be hypothesized to be due to increasing familiarity amongst Christians with the metaphysical concepts of the earlier authors. That is a tenuous link but it might be a productive one for further study.
Another point of interest is that the four places where these idioms appear all communicate a similar idea. It isn't that we find εἷς with a plural subject in contexts of baking a cake, or constituting a federal government from notionally independent states.
Which offers some prospect of εἷς conveying something special to Christians. The number's meaning beginning to change, through acquaintance with a concept of the one-who-is.

+1. Thank you for taking the time to answer in detail.

To be outspoken amongst the world that Jesus was the fulfillment of prophecy written in the Law and Prophets. To be outspoken meant publicly declaring that Jesus was Lord and Messiah while having argument to support the statement, and acknowledging that rewards and persecution because of it may happen directly and indirectly because of ONE. Joyous as a group, and suffer as a group. That is being ONE in Christ Jesus.
Does it necessarily mean that the spirit of God exists only and only within those who are ONE? No: can’t really argue that because it is the spirit of God that sustains all life. Those who are living and yet do not declare all of the aforementioned are argument of that falsehood. The neighbor’s dog has a spirit of God keeping it alive as does myself.
As Mark 10:18 says “there is no good unless One of God.” Everyone and everything can be good since it has a spirit of God. Is there only one spirit? No:but if life sustains then the spirt is One.

From my point there is a little bit more, according to texts. All the host of God, which He created, is all good, (Gen 1:31) and by that can be considered one. But this oneness has no unity nor desire for it. So creatures only bear it, and do not produce it. But the Spirit of God is different: God with Spirit creates and holds oneness. So animals don't have Spirit of God on their own, from that perspective. I think it is correct to say that the God with his Spirit owns all animals and other creatures in the way He decided. With a little except for humans.

I didn’t intend for what I wrote to be interpreted as equating humans, animals, plants, all that is alive, as being equal because it bears a spirit of God. The spirit of God already exists in that it cannot be reproduced. The creation can reproduce itself but not the spirit of God. The amount of life that exists does not affect the amount of the spirit of God. There could be 70 trillion people alive but the spirit of God still exists as though there was only two people alive.
